# What does the 28 bytes mean in ai_addr->sa_data?

Tags: sockets, networking, ipv6

I tested with "::1" and the ip address of a domain. It seems like the ipv6 address has an addrlen of 28. The first 6 was blank (I know the first two bytes of ipv4 is the 16bit port but I'm stumped here) and the last 6 bytes is blank. The middle 16bytes is the 128bit ipv6 address

What is the first 6 bytes and last 6 bytes used for?

Comment: The network structures are well-defined, with plenty of documentation and references. What references and documentation have you been using for the network functions and structures? What do they say? Perhaps a reference like [this one](http://uw714doc.xinuos.com/en/SDK_netapi/sockC.TheIPv6sockaddrstructure.html) might be helpful?

Comment: And what do you mean by "blank"? That the value is zero? That they corresponded to the character `' '`? Something else?

Comment: Oh and you shouldn't really be looking into a generic `struct sockaddr` object without casting it to its correct type. Pass it to the function that need it, yes, but don't look into it yourself. And for `struct addrinfo`, always remember to use the `ai_addrlen` member as the size of the socket address structure.

Comment: You should be casting the `sa_data` field to either `struct sockaddr_in6 *` or `struct sockaddr_in *` depending on the IP version and using the fields in those structs instead of trying to interpret the bytes manually.

Comment: @dbush nothing I seen mentioned sockaddr_in6. That helped. I now see it's a 32bit id reserved to 0 called 'flowinfo' and the bytes after the address is scopeid which I didn't see a definition for but it seems like I may not need it for my usecase

Comment: @david scopeid roughly corresponds to "network interface ID"; it's used for certain type of IPv6 address (like link-local scoped multicast addresses) to specify which local network interface the IP address is associated with.

Comment: This question doesn't seem to have anything to do with C programming.

Comment: @dbush you should not cast just the `sa_data` by itself at all. You need to cast the entire `sockaddr` as a whole instead

Comment: @RemyLebeau Right, I got the fields mixed up.  The `ai_addr` field of a `struct addrinfo` has type `struct sockaddr *`, so that's the one that should be casted, not the `sa_data` subfield.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of the `sa_data` field are dependent on the address family specified in the `sa_family` field.

When `ai_addr->sa_family` is `AF_INET`, `ai_addr` is pointing at a [`sockaddr_in`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html) struct:

```c
struct sockaddr_in {
    sa_family_t    sin_family; /* address family: AF_INET */
    in_port_t      sin_port;   /* port in network byte order */
    struct in_addr sin_addr;   /* internet address */
};

/* Internet address */
struct in_addr {
    uint32_t       s_addr;     /* address in network byte order */
};
```

Thus, `ai_addr->sa_data` contains the data for the `sin_port` and `sin_addr` fields (6 bytes). The total size of `sockaddr_in` is 8 bytes.

When `ai_addr->sa_family` is `AF_INET6`, `ai_addr` is pointing at a [`sockaddr_in6`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ipv6.7.html) struct instead:

```c
struct sockaddr_in6 {
    sa_family_t     sin6_family;   /* AF_INET6 */
    in_port_t       sin6_port;     /* port number */
    uint32_t        sin6_flowinfo; /* IPv6 flow information */
    struct in6_addr sin6_addr;     /* IPv6 address */
    uint32_t        sin6_scope_id; /* Scope ID (new in 2.4) */
};

struct in6_addr {
    unsigned char   s6_addr[16];   /* IPv6 address */
};
```

Thus, `ai_addr->sa_data` contains the data for the `sin6_port`..`sin6_scope_id` fields (26 bytes).  The total size of `sockaddr_in6` is 28 bytes (except on systems where `sin6_scope_id` is not present).

So, you need to look at the `ai_addr->sa_family` field and then type-cast `ai_addr` (or `memcpy()` it) to access the other fields correctly, eg:

```c
struct addrinfo hints, *addrs;

memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
...

int res = getaddrinfo(..., &hints, &addrs);
if (res != 0) ...
for(struct addrinfo *addr = addrs; addr != NULL; addr = addr->ai_next) {
    switch (addr->ai_addr->sa_family) {
        case AF_INET: {
            struct sockaddr_in *ip4 = (struct sockaddr_in *) addr->ai_addr;
            /* alternatively:
            struct sockaddr_in ip4;
            memcpy(&ip4, addr->ai_addr, sizeof(ip4));
            */
            // use ip4 as needed...
            break;
        }

        case AF_INET6: {
            struct sockaddr_in6 *ip6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *) addr->ai_addr;
            /* alternatively:
            struct sockaddr_in6 ip6;
            memcpy(&ip6, addr->ai_addr, sizeof(ip6));
            */
            // use ip6 as needed...
            break;
        }
    }
}
freeaddrinfo(addrs);
```